# Mudar o Contexto de acordo com a aplicação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso que na parte Web eu aponte qual contexto o sistema irá utilizar.

Meu projeto está dividido da seguinte forma:

[image: Projeto]

Após sua finalização precisei "replica-lo", porém utilizando outro banco. As tabelas são iguais não muda nada, porém é em outro banco por ser outro sistema. Apenas preciso alterar a string de conexão do web.config. Acho "MUITO ERRADO" deixar dois projetos IDÊNTICOS apenas com a string de conexão diferente.

```
namespace RepositorioEF
{
public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Cartas> Carta {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Clientes> Clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Loja_Carrossel> Carrossel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Loja_Menus> Menu { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Loja_Produtos> Produto { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Loja_Submenus> Submenu { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pedidos> Pedido { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pedidos_Itens> PedidoItem { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pedidos_Status> PedidoStatus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Loja_Codigo> Codigo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Loja_Usuarios> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Loja_ActionsLog> ActionsLog { get; set; }


    public Contexto()
        : base("BancoDados")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Contexto>(null);
    }
}
}
```

Essa é a classe do meu contexto e não sei como fazer um "IF" para determinada opção. Pensei em adicionar um outro construtor para usar a outra connection string, mas não sei se é a maneira mais adequada.

E eu chamo o contexto com essa classe:

```
namespace RepositorioEF
{
public class ClientesRepositorioEF : IRepositorio<Clientes>
{
    private readonly Contexto contexto;

    public ClientesRepositorioEF()
    {
        contexto = new Contexto();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: veja se entendi corretamente: você criou um projeto e deseja usar a mesma estrutura do projeto para um outro projeto. É isso?

Comment: Isso.. Só altera o banco de dados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só ter mais opções no construtor do seu contexto:

```
public Contexto()
    : base("BancoDados")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<Contexto>(null);
}

public Contexto(String nomeDaConnectionString)
    : base(nomeDaConnectionString)
{

}
```

Passe o nome da `ConnectionString` na hora de instanciar:

```
public class ClientesRepositorioEF : IRepositorio<Clientes>
{
    private readonly Contexto contexto1;
    private readonly Contexto contexto2;

    public ClientesRepositorioEF()
    {
        contexto1 = new Contexto();
        contexto2 = new Contexto("MinhaSegundaConnectionString");
    }
}
```

Pra usar a `ConnectionString` padrão, só não passar nada como argumento.

Comment: Poderia manter apenas o segundo construtor do Contexto? "public Contexto(String nomeDaConnectionString)
    : base(nomeDaConnectionString)" Acho meio redundante, sendo que posso passar o banco por parametro.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Pode. Apenas certifique-se de explicitar valores padrão.

Comment: Como assim? Valores padrão?

Comment: Se você passar uma `String` vazia, o código tem que funcionar. É só se certificar disso.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize [Web.config Transformation Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) para alterar a connection strings quando publicado:

Na solution explorer, procure por: `Web.Release.config` e altere a sessão desejada:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add
        xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace"
        name="{nome-da-connection-string}"
        connectionString="{connection-string-nova}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Nas configurações de publicação selecione o profile desejado:

[image: Selecionando profile na publicação de uma app web]

Você pode criar quantos profiles desejar:

[image: Novas configurações]

E adicionar novas transformações para o Web.config:

[image: Adicionar novas transformações para o Web.config]

Comment: Mas ai eu teria dois projetos ainda. Seria mais interessante eu configurar isso via código, para o sistema identificar e mudar.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, você teria apenas um projeto com N transformações de Web.config.

Comment: @Ridermansb Acho que o que ele quer é ter dois contextos trabalhando ao mesmo tempo em bases diferentes. A transformação é outro aspecto, referente mais à publicação do projeto em produção.

Comment: Entendi seu argumento, teria que efetuar vários publishs para cada cliente (o que não é o ideal). Neste caso o ideal seria via código mesmo.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Exatamente!